# NSUserDefaults problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two views.In One view when i click on custom button it goes into second view,In that i have text view and that data must store in temperary memory so i used following code:

```
NSString *myString=txtvNote.text;
[txtvNote setText:@""];

NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (standardUserDefaults) {
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"note"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```

and when i go back on 1st view by clicking on the add button it will save into database for that i used following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *val = nil;

if (standardUserDefaults) 
    val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"note"];
NSLog(@"Note::%@",val);
```

and then pass this value in insert query.
Now my problem is when i left that value blank,it takes the value which is inserted before.

Comment: Please explain: "when i left that value blank".  When, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myString` is a pointer to the text in `txtvNote`. So if you set that text to @"" then myString will be empty as well. To preserve the value of txtvNote at the time of assignment use `copy` or reset the text after saving it:

```
 NSString *myString=[[txtvNote.text copy] autorelease]; 
 [txtvNote setText:@""];
 ....
```

Answer (score 2):

sequence must be like this

//first set text to something

```
 [txtvNote setText:@""];
```

//then use that text

```
 NSString *myString=txtvNote.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the way NSUserDefaults works - every value is stored in your app's preferences, and like any other collection in Obj-C, it doesn't take `nil` values. Use instance of `NSNull` class or empty string. Or even better - use intermediate controller to store values and use key-value observing in your first view.